# Windows 10 BLE Advertise as custom peripheral

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can Windows 10 be configured to advertise itself as a custom peripheral instead of a central, using whatever standard Bluetooth hardware a laptop has? I'd like to advertise as a temperature peripheral to test communication with a different BLE central.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 does not yet implement LE peripheral role or GATT Server.

You can still send an advertisement where you pretend to be the temperature peripheral, but your central will not be able to connect to you over LE.